# Issue uploading a file second time in fedora 4.4 version after cancelling the uploading process in the middle

Tags: fedora, fedora-commons

We are uploading a file of nearly 50G using a python script to the fedora repository. And we had to cancel it abruptly (Ctrl+C) as we had sudden downtime needed on the repository server.

Now, we are unable to upload the file again. I can not see the file listed in the object metadata xml. I get the following error while uploading:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "create_datastream2.py", line 386, in
>
> ```
> dsresponse = s.send(prepped)
> ```
>
> File
>   "/opt/python_2_7_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
>   line 576, in send
>
> ```
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> File
>   "/opt/python_2_7_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
>   line 426, in send
>
> ```
> raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
> ```
>
> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',
>   error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

And I can upload any other file without any issues. Just this particular where we stopped abruptly, it fails.

Any ideas?  I can share you the uploading script if you need.

**Update 1:** 
Actually, now I remember, I deleted that file from the web portal thinking it might be partial file. And that created the tombstone and preventing another file to be uploaded again with same name.

To fix this, all I had to do is delete that tombstone using DELETE request.

So, I guess it doesn't cause any issue if a file upload is cancelled abruptly? Any ideas what happens to the partially uploaded file?. Does it have any left overs and occupy any space in the disk? And `java.io.tmpdir` is pointing to a disk with enough disk space (1TB). So, does the file is saved here temporarily while uploading and then gets deleted if the upload is cancelled? I can't find any file there though while uploading except this: `safeToDelete.tmp`